# Execute a T-SQL job with a different connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure from a SQL agent job while specifying a custom Application Name, similar to specifying the Application Name in a connection string?

The reason I want to do this is is to a avoid a trigger on the database that specifically distinguished on the Application Name used by the connection string.

I know you can execute an integration package with a different connection string, but I hope this is possible for T-sql jobs as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but here are a few alternatives:

1. Use [`OPENDATASOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms179856%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) like this:

   ```
   EXEC OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master;Application Name="test app"')
       .master.sys.sp_configure;
   ```

   Note that using `OPENDATASOURCE` requires you to turn on the `Ad hoc Distributed Queries` `sp_configure` setting (as noted in the Remarks section of the documentation) even though you won't be writing code that accesses another server (SQL Server doesn't know that).
2. Create a wrapper SSIS package that specifies the application name in a Connection Manager, and then uses an Execute SQL task to run the stored procedure.
3. Create a wrapper command-line app that takes a connection string and a command as parameters; execute it using an Operating System (cmdexec) job step.

Comment: Option one will work I think. The reason is that I want to be able to set up the SP and the Job using a .net Gui, so I want to avoid using packages or other files. Thanks!

Comment: @user196124: You're welcome. There are many ways to do what you want (I think even something like a SQL CLR procedure, or PowerShell as mentioned in the other answer); it comes down to which types of objects you want to set up. (Having said that, I do like the PowerShell approach.)

Comment: It works :-) I can now set up a job and schedule it just by executing some sql code from my .net application, without having to worry about files.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a PowerShell script to achieve this and have that called from the SQL Agent which allows PowerShell as one of the command types:

Here's some code to help you get started:

```
Function Get-MyConnectionString{
    param(
        [string]$Server,
        [string]$Database,
        [string]$UserName,
        [string]$Password,
        [string]$ApplicationName
        )

    If (!($ApplicationName)) { $ApplicationName = "PowerShell (Unknown)" }

    $SqlConnectionBuilder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    $SqlConnectionBuilder["Data Source"] = $Server;
    $SqlConnectionBuilder["Application Name"] = $ApplicationName;



    If (!(($UserName -eq $null) -or ($UserName -eq ""))) {
        $SqlConnectionBuilder["User ID"] = $UserName
        $SqlConnectionBuilder["Password"] = $Password
    }
    Else {
        $SqlConnectionBuilder["Integrated Security"] = $true
    }

    If (!(($Database -eq $null) -or ($Database -eq ""))){
        $SqlConnectionBuilder["Initial Catalog"] = $Database
    }

    #SWrite-Debug ("Built connection string: {0}" -f $SqlConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString)
    Write-Output ($SqlConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString)
}

Function Invoke-MySqlCmd
{
    param(
        [string]$Server,
        [string]$Database,
        [string]$UserName,
        [string]$Password,
        [string]$Query,
        [string]$ApplicationName="My Application"
        )

    # Build the connection string
    $ConnectionString = (Get-MyConnectionString -Server $Server -Database $Database -Username $UserName -Password $Password -ApplicationName $ApplicationName)
    #Write-Debug("Using connection string: {0}" -f $ConnectionString);

    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Connection.Open()

    $SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query, $Connection);
    $SqlDataSet = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $SqlDataAdapter = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlCommand)

    [void]$SqlDataAdapter.Fill($SqlDataSet)
    $Connection.Close()

    Write-Output ($SqlDataSet.Tables)
}
```